# HTML page not showing values

Tags: jquery, python, html, django

I a have a Python web app that sending parameter from the database to an HTML page 
when the page is loaded i cant see the result.

I have check in the network tab in inspect mode and i  can see  the values are getting to the page .

The parameter that are not presented in the page are:
chaccount_id ,bank_name ,Company, seq_id

This is my code :

```
<form id="accounts_form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% load staticfiles %}
Account Number:<input  list="accountslist" id="accounts_id" name="accountsname"  value="{{ Account_id }}" >
<button id="getacc_id" type="submit" name="getacc" value="commit">Get Account Details</button>
 <img id="GETACC_loading" src="{% static "app/images/small_loading.gif" %}" hidden>
    <br />   <br />
  <br /><br />

   <datalist id="accountslist">
     <select id="accounslist" size="5">
         {% for account in  accounts  %}
         <option value="{{ account.0 }}"></option>
         {% endfor %}
         </select>
     </datalist>

   </form>


<table id="theTable" hidden>
<thead>
<tr>
      <td>Account id</td>
      <td>Bank Name</td>
      <td>Company Name</td>
      <td> Counter</td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td>{{ chaccount_id }}</td>
  <td>{{ bank_name }}</td>
  <td>{{ Company }}</td>
  <td>{{ seq_id }}</td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>
 {% endblock %}
{% block scripts %}
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#getacc_id').click(function(evt){
               acctoshow=document.getElementById('accounts_id').value;
                evt.preventDefault();
            $('#GETACC_loading').show();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'Accountinfo',
                data: {
                    'acctoshow' : acctoshow,
                    'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'
                },
                success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    $('#theTable').DataTable(
           {

               stateSave: true,
               "sDom": 'C<"clear">rfrtip',
               "scrollCollapse": true,
               "paging": true,
               responsive: true
        });    
    $('#theTable').show();             
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    $('#rb_loading').hide();
                    alert("could not find accoutn detials, please try again!");
                }
            })
        });

     $('#updaterec_id').click(function () {
            bankname=document.getElementById('newbanks_id').value;
            companyname=document.getElementById('newcompany_id').value;
            counterid=document.getElementById('ncounterid').value;
            accid=document.getElementById('retriveacc_id').value;
            $('#GETACC_loading').show();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'Accountinfo',
                data: {
                    'bank' : bankname,
                    'company' : companyname,
                    'seq' : counterid,
                    'account' : accid,
                    'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'
                },
                success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                      $('#GETACC_loading').hide();      
                     alert("Account Details were updated!");
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    $('#GETACC_loading').hide();
                    alert("could not update account detials, please try again!");
                }
            })
        });

      });
    </script>
    {% endblock %}
```

Thanks ,

Nir

Comment: What python framework are you using? Could you show some code?

Comment: i am using Django

Comment: And how about letting us help you, we need to know a little about what is not working :) would you be interested in showing some code? Or at least any errors you are getting?

Comment: What do you mean? you dont see the code above ? the problem is not with Python for sure , as i can see that the parameters arrive to the html page

Comment: This is becoming a very frequently asked question. If you are using Ajax, **you need to do something with the data in your success method**.

Comment: When using templates you do not send the values over Ajax, it is normally rendered in in the document request, as @bluszcz mentioned.

Comment: I solved it, i used JsonResponse rather then render

Answer (score 0):

You should pass your data in context, using a render function for example: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/shortcuts/#render

Comment: Thanks, but as i wrote above i can see that the data received in HTML page just not presented.

Comment: What do you mean by not presented?